# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1/n) \sum_{k=1}^n ka_k = 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

the series $a_n$ is any arbitrary converging series.

My thought process was that the $1/n$ will definitely go to zero as n approaches infinity; however, the series $k*a_k$ seems to approach infinity at the same rate. This confuses me because if both the numerator and denominator approach infinity, I think that the overall equation will equal 1, not zero.

I also considered that the sum is geometric, but I do not believe that is the case, because both $a_k$ and $k$ are variables that are not constant. I was thinking that I could argue if the series $a_k$ converges to a point, eventually the terms of the sequence will be so close to each other that it resembles a constant multiplier, but that argument is not very strong.

Any tips, hints, or leads at the solution are appreciated!

Comment: What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$?

Comment: it is an arbitrary sequence that converges

Comment: And where does $x$ come in? You meant $n$ I suppose.

Comment: you're right, I'm new to MathJax

Comment: And you also meant $k*a_k$? Because $\lim_{n \to 0} a_n$ doesnt make much sense. I'm not trying to be rude, I'm just trying to understand the question so I could maybe help.

Comment: I'm so embarressed, the limit as n goes to infinity, not zero

Comment: Even with $k.a_k$, it's wrong, take $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: okay, now everything seems in order, thank you for the updates!!

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. The hypothesis is that $x_n$ converges to some $x$. Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)a_k$, and recall (or if necessary, prove) that if $y_n\to y$ then $$\hat y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\to y$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** from the convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$, we know that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ has bounded partial sums. We have:

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\,a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}\,a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)a_k. $$
Now apply [Dirichlet's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) to the last sum regarded as a series.

Once you know that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\,a_k$ is convergent, convergence to zero follows from the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: I'm not convinced Dirichlet is applicable here, since you do not know that $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$.

Comment: @OriaGruber: the other way. $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ has bounded partial sums and $\left(1-k/n\right)$ is decreasing to zero.

Comment: That only shows convergence - not convergence to 0.

Comment: @A.S.: once you know that convergence holds, the other part is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_k = \sum_{j=1}^{k}a_j.$ We are given $S_k \to$ some $L.$ Summing by parts, we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}ka_k = nS_n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}S_k.$$
Dividing by $n$ gives $S_n$ minus $(n-1)/n$ times the $(n-1)$st Cesaro mean of the $S_k,$ which also converges to $L.$ Our limit is therefore $L-L=0.$

Comment: You had an incorrect solution, which you deleted. I didn't see your new solution, which was posted 27 seconds before mine. I think I'll leave mine up.

Comment: Hehe, no problem.

Comment: (The solution had a typo, to be fair =) )